# Whats the difference between Team Fortress 2 and Team Fortress 2 Beta?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

In Steam I haven't played TF2 for a while and when I loaded Steam there was an available game for download: Team Fortress 2 Beta. I know this sounds stupid...but what's the diff between the two? Should I download the Beta version when I already have a ton of achievements on the other? Or is this just some legacy stuff that people still go back to playing to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *Team Fortress 2 Beta* game is where the devs test changes to the game prior to rolling them out officially.  It isn't intended to replace the "real" game for normal play; the rules for acquiring items are very different, for example, to facilitate testing.

More detailed information is available from [the official wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Team_Fortress_2_Beta).

Answer (score -1):

As said above,

> The Team Fortress 2 Beta game is where the devs test changes to the game prior to rolling them out officially. It isn't intended to replace the "real" game for normal play; the rules for acquiring items are very different, for example, to facilitate testing.

People sometimes use it as a fun mode because servers can hand out test items, or for more fair play. The last change to the beta was long, long ago.